# How to return an html document from WebApi 2 action using IHttpActionResult interface?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-web-api

I need to build an html document and return it in my web api. All available answers on the net and the forum suggest using HttpResponseMessage. I would like to achieve this by IHttpActionResult. Below is what I have thus far:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNotesViewModels()
    {
        var note = await GetHtmlText();
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StringContent(note);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

        return Ok(ResponseMessage(response));
    }
```

I am not receiving what I would like. What is missing here?

Comment: By using `Ok()` you are wrapping your response inside a `NegotiatedContentResult`, which will try to serialize your `HttpResponseMessage` into json (or xml). Web Api 2 supports `HttpResponseMessage` as return type directly: just use it instead of `IHttpActionResult` and return you `response` object.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma excellent. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own HtmlResult, like following (free-handed):

```
public class HtmlActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public HtmlActionResult (HttpRequestMessage request, string content)
    {
        Request = request;
        Content= content;
    }

    public string Content { get; private set; }
    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(ExecuteResult());
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage ExecuteResult()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Content))
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

        response.RequestMessage = Request;
        return response;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNotesViewModels()
    {
        var note = await GetHtmlText();
        return new HtmlActionResult(Request, note);
    }
```